# Trying to select a specific element. How do I change all other elements that aren't selected to false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to build a select function for my object. The issue is when I click another element the other elements remain selected.

How can I set all other elements to isSelected: false, after selecting the element I want.

I need a way so that when I set the state of the element I want to true, it will set all other element states to false.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// The parent component
const App = () => {
  const [textBoxDivs, setTextBoxDivs] = useState({});

  const addNewTextBox = () => {
    const numOfTextBoxDivs = Object.keys(textBoxDivs).length;
    console.log(numOfTextBoxDivs, "num");
    setTextBoxDivs({
      ...textBoxDivs,
      [`div${numOfTextBoxDivs + 1}`]: {
        isSelected: false,
        innerText: "text"
      }
    });
  };

  const selectItem = (e) => {
    if (e) {
      const selectedItemKey = e.target.id;
      setTextBoxDivs({
        ...textBoxDivs,
        [selectedItemKey]: {
          ...textBoxDivs[selectedItemKey],
          isSelected: true
        }
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => addNewTextBox()}>
        Click me to create a selectable div
      </button>

      {Object.keys(textBoxDivs).length > 0 &&
        Object.keys(textBoxDivs).map((key, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              style={{
                border: textBoxDivs[key].isSelected
                  ? "2px solid green"
                  : "unset"
              }}
              onClick={(e) => selectItem(e)}
              key={index}
              id={key}
            >
              {textBoxDivs[key].innerText}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-water-wf4f5?file=/src/App.js:0-1385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, `e` will be defined, so no need to check it.

I would do something like this:

```
const selectItem = (e) => {

  const selectedItemKey = e.target.id;

  const nextState = {...textBoxDivs}
  Object.keys(nextState).forEach(k => {
     nextState[k].isSelected = false
  })

  nextState[selectedItemKey].isSelected = true

  setTextBoxDivs(nextState);
};
```

I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it with a `selected` state object, so each `div` only needs to check whether or not it's the selected one.

Add a state object to keep track of `selected`

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
```

Change the ternary operator to `selected == key ? "2px solid green" : "unset"`. Also, change your `onClick` to `() => setSelected(key)`

```
<div
  style={{
    border: selected == key ? "2px solid green" : "unset"
  }}
  onClick={() => setSelected(key)}
  key={index}
  id={key}
>
```

Then remove your `selectItem()` function.

Here's the full code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [textBoxDivs, setTextBoxDivs] = useState({});
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();

  const addNewTextBox = () => {
    const numOfTextBoxDivs = Object.keys(textBoxDivs).length;
    console.log(numOfTextBoxDivs, "num");
    setTextBoxDivs({
      ...textBoxDivs,
      [`div${numOfTextBoxDivs + 1}`]: {
        isSelected: false,
        innerText: "text"
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => addNewTextBox()}>
        Click me to create a selectable div
      </button>

      {Object.keys(textBoxDivs).length > 0 &&
        Object.keys(textBoxDivs).map((key, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              style={{
                border: selected === key ? "2px solid green" : "unset"
              }}
              onClick={() => setSelected(key)}
              key={index}
              id={key}
            >
              {textBoxDivs[key].innerText}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I think this will make your code more readable, and it reduces the number of lines you'll need to achieve the desired effect by completely removing the need for your `selectItem` function.